# JSP Taglib c:import url from file

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I configured my JSP pages to import header and footer from another jsp, as follow:

`< c:import url="/WEB-INF/views/jsp/header.jsp" />`

I would like to know if it is possible to read this url from a file/variable instead of writing the full url on every page, so if the path changes I just have to rewrite a single line instead of all pages.

Thanks!

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Then you can accept it and upvote it, by clicking on the check-mark and arrow-up on the left side. If you still have trouble, please provide more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use context parameter in the web.xml like this:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>jsp-header</param-name>
    <param-value>header.jsp</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

And access it in the JPS file like that:

```
<c:import url="<%=application.getInitParameter("jsp-header")%>"/>
```

EDIT:

Even better will be:

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <include-prelude>header.jspf</include-prelude>
        <include-coda>footer.jspf</include-coda>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Note also the extension `jspf` (with ending `f` for fragment).

The `<c:import/>` won't be needed anymore.

Comment: Thx for your answer, I tried to do the following: Created the <jsp-config> on web.xml <br/>

`<jsp-config> 
<jsp-property-group> 
<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
<include-prelude>/WEB-INF/views/jsp/header.jspf</include-pre‌​lude> <include-coda>/WEB-INF/views/jsp/footer.jspf</include-coda>
</jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>`

 I receive the folloowing error:

`message /WEB-INF/views/index.jsp (line: 1, column: 1) File [/WEB-INF/views/jsp/header.jspf] not found `

The path is correct. I am using Spring MVC, should I use a different configuration for Spring?

Comment: did you republished and synchronized?

Comment: go back to the `jsp` extension? Any improvement?